# Garage door opener not learning remotes anymore

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a 3/4 Craftsman Garage Door opener that came with my house of indeterminate age. A few months back, all but one of the remotes stopped working on the unit, as well as the external keypad. On the keypad, it looks like it was a battery thing that stopped it briefly. However, I can't seem to program either my other remote, or the external keypad, on the internal unit. I followed the stated process several times of pressing the learn button, bringing the remote over, or the external keypad, and typing in the code, but I don't get the flash of light indicating that it's learned it, and the code doesn't go in. I've tried several variations on ways to go about it, including holding the buttons for less or more time.

I am mildly at my wits end here. A visit from the garage door repair company that we have used before will cost me about half as much as buying a new opener unit. Thought, honestly, I'm not certain of my mechanical prowess to install one, so there would be some extra expense there.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can get this working? We are currently down to one remote, and I just managed to accidentally lock myself out today. Fortunately, a neighbor is coming by with a key to the front door, so that I will be able to get inside the house to open up the garage door from the inside. The wired button on the inside is still working, of course.

[image: Image showing the model serial number] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Have you tried unpluging the lift motor for 10-20 seconds, then try the learning process?

Comment: I did. And I have also tried holding the button to try to make it forget. In both cases, it doesn't seem to have actually forgotten the one remote.

Comment: And you replaced the batteries in the remote that you're trying to program?

Comment: Yes. And on the external keypad. And I've verified that they blink when the button is pushed.

Comment: I've replace my garage door opener twice, once with a Craftsman, once with a Chamberlain.   The bolt holes were the exact same layout so it was relatively easy: reused the chain and the optical sensors.

Comment: Most "brands" of opener are *really* Chamberlains, with another name stuck on them. Or that seems to be the case In the US, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers don't live forever.

Garage door openers have tiny computers, and they also don't live forever.

While you can replace the logic board, in many cases, that is typically half the cost of a new opener, and typically both non-returnable and without any warranty; while a whole new opener **does** come with a warranty.

I've replaced a logic board once. It was a dice roll, but the opener was fairly new and there had been a known lightning strike nearby just before it started acting up.

In general, it's not a good dice roll with an opener so old you don't know how old it is. (well, actually about 16-1/3 years, per the labeled date of 9/06.) Do put a surge suppressor on the outlet for the new one.

Comment: Agree 100%. I've had a garage door opener for 28 years. I'm on my 3rd one. 16 years is a pretty good life span. It's done yeoman's service, give it a gold watch and retire it.

Comment: I bought the new opener yesterday, and will install it on Friday with the help of a friend. I watched a tutorial or two online. It does look fairly easy, but it will be nice to have that second set of hands to hold it in place.